# Why is access to this file denied when trying to overwrite to it via PowerShell out-file

Tags: powershell

PowerShell is being really picky for me. I am trying to overwrite a ps1 file from another ps1 file. Seems easy enough, I just use Out-File and specify the path and input object, done. "Access to path is denied."

1. Running PowerShell as admin
2. Execution Policy is Unrestricted
3. The file isn't read-only (albeit the folder its in keeps reverting to read-only)
4. The variable I am passing is simply a string

```
    $Template = Get-Content -Path ($Destination + "\Deploy-Application.ps1") -Raw #Preferably a relative path so it's not hard-coded
    [string]$Formatted = $Template -f $FormatArray
    
    Out-File -FilePath $Destination -InputObject $Formatted -Force
```

What other reasons explain why this code is not receiving access to write to the file?

Comment: Your `-FilePath` doesn't include the file name.

Comment: I have now also tried taking ownership of the folder the file is in to no avail.

Comment: AdminOfThings, is right. Another set of eyes really helps, can't believe I didnt see that, TY.